# How can i use the output of mapreduce wordcount for further processing?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have done a map-reduce wordcount program, now i want use the output(which is a word-count of each word) from which i want to count top 5 keywords. How to use the output of stage 1 into stage 2,should i run another job?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly write another job reading from the output of first.

Consider your task to have 2 steps:
Step 1: Word count
Step 2: Top n words

In step 2, have an [IdentityMapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/IdentityMapper.html) and make sure you have a single reducer(`job.setNumReduceTasks( NO_OF_REDUCERS );`), then in reducer you can keep track of topN and emit them at end, for this you shall [override the run()](http://www.bigdataspeak.com/2013/02/how-to-perform-global-aggregation-or_25.html) of reducer.

You can also, edit your Step1 itself and make it to have just one reducer, and keep track of topN words and emit them at last. But if you have a lot of word then this method be more time consuming than having 2 separate steps.

Comment: Or, instead of an identity mapper, reverse keys with values, so that counts are the keys and words are values. Hadoop will sort them in the reduce phase, and you can just keep the top/lower n words (again with a single reducer).